# Increasing Limit of Tables on Local DynamoDB

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is this possible? For the live version, I can increase it to as many as I want, but locally I'm restricted to 256 tables and now stuck not being able to create new tables. I was looking around for documentation on how to this and have no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you have a limit to 256 tables per region.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html

"Tables Per Account

For any AWS account, there is an initial limit of 256 tables per region.

To request a service limit increase see https://aws.amazon.com/support."

So, if you need more tables, you will need to request a service limit increase with their support.

Comment: I'm asking about local instance. For live instance, I don't have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -help
```

And see if there are any useful parameters exposed in the help.  It is very likely that it is not possible to change the table limits in the local version of DynamoDb.

You could try running two instances of DynamoDB (on different ports) and then code your app to use two connectors.  Making them the same in production.

Comment: I just found my copy of DynamoDBLocal and it doesn't have much help at all.